# While installing Sitecore 9 update 2 got below issue

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS P:\> D:
PS D:\> cd sc9_install
PS D:\sc9_install> .\sc9_install
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The term 'Install-SitecoreConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:29 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SitecoreConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The term 'Install-SitecoreConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:40 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SitecoreConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The term 'Install-SitecoreConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:57 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SitecoreConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The term 'Install-SitecoreConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:68 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SitecoreConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The term 'Install-SitecoreConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At D:\sc9_install\sc9_install.ps1:87 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SitecoreConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Which version of powershell are you running here? You need to be on Powershell 5.1. 
The 2014 copyright at the top of your log suggests you are running an older version. Run `$PSVersionTable` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is due to the Sitecore Installation Framework not being installed/registered.

You should be able to register the Powershell module by executing the following statements:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2
Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework 
Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, it could be due to a manual install of the framework previously that needs to be removed first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the following steps to work with it correctly.

#### Enabling PowerShell Policy to allow to run commands

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

#### Add the Sitecore MyGet repository to PowerShell

```
Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2
```

#### Install the Sitecore Install Framwork module and Sitecore Fundamentals module (provides additional functionality for local installations like creating self-signed certificates)

```
Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
Install-Module SitecoreFundamentals
```

#### Trusted reop PSGallery & SitecoreGallery

```
Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Set-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

#### Import the modules into your current PowerShell context (if not already done)

```
Import-Module SitecoreFundamentals
Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
```

You can follow this blog for complete installation steps.

https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/

Comment: Thanks for he Update. but i got the below error C:\Windows\system32> register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2
register-PSRepository : The specified Uri 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2' for parameter
'SourceLocation' is an invalid Web Uri. Please ensure that it meets the Web Uri requirements.+ register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation

Comment: https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2 tjis url is not working

Comment: Check this link, you will understand what you have missed. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_powershell_public_nuget_feed_faq

Comment: make sure you are running the PowerShell in Administrator mode

Comment: Thanks,  but i  was trying to install it in client enviroment and this URL is disable for me . (sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2) so is there any other way to do it manually

Comment: Here you can install it manually.. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/installing-sitecore-9_3a00_-install-the-sitecore-installation-framework-module

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Barron said, Sitecore installation framework is not installed properly. If you are not much comfortable with powershell, you can go for SIF-less tool.

http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/10/introducing-sif-less-for-easy-sitecore-9-installation/